# Divide list of numbers into given number parts with certain range

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a project where I have to divide numbers into certain parts.

right now I have 2 numbers max number: 300 and min number 240.

Here a person can add any number such as 5 so all numbers will show in the range such as 300, 285,270,255,240.

My code is:

```
$amp_starting_price         = 300;
$amp_lowest_accepted_price  = 240;
$quantity_available = 5);

$r = range($amp_lowest_accepted_price, $amp_starting_price, $quantity_available);
```

> Output:  Array (
> [0] => 240
> [1] => 245
> [2] => 250
> [3] => 255
> [4] => 260
> [5] => 265
> [6] => 270
> [7] => 275
> [8] => 280
> [9] => 285
> [10] => 290
> [11] => 295
> [12] => 300 )

This is how I need it to show. Divide into 5 or any given number of parts into a particular range such as 300 to 240.

> Output:  Array (
> [0] => 240
> [3] => 255
> [6] => 270
> [9] => 285
> [12] => 300 )

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected? Show desired vs. actual outcome.

Comment: Desired output: Output: Array ( [0] => 240 [3] => 255 [6] => 270 [9] => 285 [12] => 300 )

Comment: Actual output. 
Output: Array ( [0] => 240 [1] => 245 [2] => 250 [3] => 255 [4] => 260 [5] => 265 [6] => 270 [7] => 275 [8] => 280 [9] => 285 [10] => 290 [11] => 295 [12] => 300 )

Answer (score 1):

I have edited my first answer to fully fit the desired output:

```
<?php
// set number of parts including the start point
$parts = 5;

// set the increment 
$increment = 5;

// set max and min values of the range
$amp_starting_price         = 300;
$amp_lowest_accepted_price  = 240;

// check if division is exact and all parts will be equal in number
if (($mod = fmod(($amp_starting_price-$amp_lowest_accepted_price), ($parts-1))) == 0) {
    $quantity_available = ($amp_starting_price-$amp_lowest_accepted_price)/($parts-1);
} else {
    die("Error: Division is not exact. Exist a floating point remainder: $mod\n");
}

// get the increment range
$r_increment = range($amp_lowest_accepted_price, $amp_starting_price, $increment);

// get the parts range
$r_parts = range($amp_lowest_accepted_price, $amp_starting_price, $quantity_available);

// output the result
print_r(array_intersect($r_increment,$r_parts));
```

It outputs this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 240
    [3] => 255
    [6] => 270
    [9] => 285
    [12] => 300
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But it is not showing desired output.
Desired output: 
Array ( [0] => 240 [3] => 255 [6] => 270 [9] => 285 [12] => 300 )

Your code output:
Array
(
    [0] => 240
    [1] => 300
)

Comment: If you execute the exact code that I have post you should see this output: Array(    [0] => 240    [1] => 255    [2] => 270    [3] => 285    [4] => 300).  Are the array index numbers important to you? I mean, do you need to use [0] [3] [6] [9] [12] instead the [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]?

Comment: Yes now showing correctly. Thanks

Comment: In the previous try, I just miss the 2 keywords above $parts and $increment. Thanks again

Comment: Is there a way I also can create decimal values such as 240.5, 255.1, 270.8 so on?

Comment: It depends of the `$increment` value. You can use float numbers there too, as `2.5` but I am not sure at 100% that it will run in all cases because in this case you have to calculate the parts too due the `if()` condition set (or remove it but then the parts won't be fully equals)